# MongooseJS: How to remove 1 object inside Array in Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hi **MongooseJS** experts!

I'm new in **MongooseJS**, This is my 2nd day of solving this problem but I can't find a working solution to this.

Thank you in advance!

**My Delete method**

```
Cart.updateOne(
    { "content.merchantId": req.body.merchantId },
    { $pull: { "content.items._id": req.body.productId } },
    { new: true },
    function (error, result) {
      if (error) { }
      else if (result) { }
    }
);
```

**Schema**

```
const CartSchema = new Schema({
      customerId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      content: {
        merchantName: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        merchantId: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        items: [],
      },
});
```

**Sample JSON**

```
[
    {
        "content": {
            "merchantName": "SAMPLE_MERCHANT_NAME",
            "merchantId": "SAMPLE_MERCHANT_ID",
            "items": [
                {
                    "_id": "SAMPLE_ID",
                    "title": "SAMPLE TITLE",
                }
            ]
        },
        "_id": "618220e83966345ab5d451cd",
        "__v": 0
    },
]
```

**Error message**

```
Cannot use the part (_id) of (content.items._id) to traverse the element ({items: [{ _id: "SAMPLE_ID", title: "SAMPLE TITLE"}] })
```

Comment: What's the problem ? Is there any error message ? Can you include the Schema for the Document ?

Comment: Hi there, the error message is 

Cannot use the part (_id) of (content.items._id) to traverse the element ({items: [ { _id: "SAMPLE_ID", title: "SAMPLE TITLE"} ]})

Comment: you couldn't remove _id because its required

Comment: Hi @mohammad, wdym by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use like this

```
db.collection.update({
  "content.merchantId": "SAMPLE_MERCHANT_ID"
},
{
  $pull: {
    "content.items": {
      "_id": "SAMPLE_ID"
    }
  }
},
{
  new:true
},
)
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ou26tab2mBU